# Windows store app - split example, show groups

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I'm using default split example for my program, but i'm facing one problem here. The application does not show's me group's that contain's no item's. Ok that makes sense, but in my case I have to show groups either way, if they contains items or not.

How can I achieve that? For now I have one sample item for every group, that makes them visible. I have to use this "trick", because when my app start's it contain's no item's at all. I get them using ajax request when I click on any group(using some api in background, so I have to do this way).

Comment: in what context are you not seeing the group? I took the Split App sample, commented out all of the items in Group 2 and the group appears on the first page, and when clicked shows the group header, but no items (obviously)

Comment: sorry, just realized this was JavaScript. That implementation does create the list based on items versus groups, so an itemless group never 'leaves' the generateSampleData method.  The fake element, perhaps with a property indicating it's fake might be the path of least resistence; otherwise, you'll need to rework how the data is populated and bound, which is certainly possible, but more work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I already have one sample(fake) item in every group. So groups are visible, but it is not pretty solution :)

Comment: right, understood, but I think doing otherwise will require a substantial rewrite of the underlying data model used there, so depends on how pretty it needs to be versus time you have :)